# inconsistent postgres statement timeout

Tags: postgresql, timeout

I set the postgres `statement_timeout` to a low value to refrain from long queries using:

```
ALTER DATABASE web SET statement_timeout = '28s';
```

Evidently some long statements indeed timeout and some don't and simply remain stuck.
What could cause this different behavior?
Does the timeout depend on the type of query? on the transaction stage? on anything else?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what is timing out and what is not?